# Updating a date in Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, peoplesoft

I am trying to update a date in a SQL table.  I am using Peoplesoft Oracle.  When I run this query:

```
Select ASOFDATE from PASOFDATE;
```

I get 4/16/2012

I tried running this query

```
UPDATE PASOFDATE SET ASOFDATE = '11/21/2012';
```

but it is not working.

Does anyone know how I would change the date to the one desired?

Comment: Define `Not Working`... Error messages? Unexpected results?

Comment: can you try: UPDATE PASOFDATE SET ASOFDATE = '11-21-2012';

Comment: I want to try that but I am afraid I won't be able to change it back to the date with the slashes...

Comment: does it make a difference whether the date has dashes or slashes?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This is based on the *assumption* that you're getting an error about the date format, such as an invalid month value or non-numeric character when numeric expected.

Dates stored in the database do not have formats. When you query the date your client is formatting the date for display, as `4/16/2011`. Normally the same date format is used for selecting and updating dates, but in this case they appear to be different - so your client is apparently doing something more complicated that SQL*Plus, for example.

When you try to update it it's using a default [date format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#sthref394). Because of how it's displayed you're assuming that is `MM/DD/YYYY`, but it seems not to be. You could find out what it is, but it's better not to rely on the default or any implicit format models at all.

Whether that is the problem or not, you should always specify the date model:

```
UPDATE PASOFDATE SET ASOFDATE = TO_DATE('11/21/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Since you aren't specifying a time component - all Oracle `DATE` columns include a time, even if it's midnight - you could also use a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#sthref362):

```
UPDATE PASOFDATE SET ASOFDATE = DATE '2012-11-21';
```

You should maybe check that the current value doesn't include a time, though the column name suggests it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you set the date and time:

```
update user set expiry_date=TO_DATE('31/DEC/2017 12:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') where id=123;
```

Answer (score 2):

If this SQL is being used in any peoplesoft specific code (Application Engine, SQLEXEC, SQLfetch, etc..) you could use %Datein metaSQL. Peopletools automatically converts the date to a format which would be accepted by the database platform the application is running on.

In case this SQL is being used to perform a backend update from a query analyzer (like SQLDeveloper, SQLTools), the date format that is being used is wrong. Oracle expects the date format to be DD-MMM-YYYY, where MMM could be JAN, FEB, MAR, etc..

Comment: Good for when one is using a 3rd party update tool, not writing their own SQL.  ++

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Alex Poole's answer, here is how you do the date and time:

```
    TO_DATE('31/DEC/2017 12:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```